# PackageManager.QueryIntentActivities() does not work?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

Documentation states that queryIntentActicities(Intent intent, int flags) is deprecated in API level 33, and to use this instead: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#queryIntentActivities(android.content.Intent,%20android.content.pm.PackageManager.ResolveInfoFlags)

But when I use it, VS says

> CS1061: 'PackageManager' does not contain a definition for
> 'ResolveInfoFlags' accepting a first argument of type 'PaclageManager'
> could be found

What am I missing?

**Xamarin.Android (C#)**:

```
private bool IsThereAnAppToTakePictures()
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Android.Provider.MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
            System.Collections.Generic.IList<ResolveInfo> availableActivities = ((int)Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt > 32) ? PackageManager.QueryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.ResolveInfoFlags) : 
                PackageManager.QueryIntentActivities(intent, PackageInfoFlags.MatchDefaultOnly);
            return availableActivities != null && availableActivities.Count > 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have checked the official document and found that the `ResolveInfoFlags` was added into the class `Android.Content.PM.PackageManager` in the Android API 33.

So you need to set the Target Framework in your project as Android 13.0 Tiramisu if you want to use this.

I updated the Visual Studio to the last version 17.3.0 Preview 5.0, and then I can use it.

But I can't find a way to get the instance of it. I tried the following code:

```
var resolveInfoFlags = new PackageManager.ResolveInfoFlags()
// but there is no construction method without any parameters
Intent intent = new Intent(Android.Provider.MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
System.Collections.Generic.IList<ResolveInfo> availableActivities = ((int)Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt > 32) ? PackageManager.QueryIntentActivities(intent, resolveInfoFlags) :
            PackageManager.QueryIntentActivities(intent, PackageInfoFlags.MatchDefaultOnly);

 and
  // the ResolveInfoFlags.Of(long value) will return a ResolveInfoFlags
  PackageManager.QueryIntentActivities(intent, Android.Content.PM.PackageManager.ResolveInfoFlags.Of(1234)) :
            PackageManager.QueryIntentActivities(intent, PackageInfoFlags.MatchDefaultOnly);
```

Comment: Does this resolve your problem? @angleUr

Answer (score 0):

You need to change syntax :

##### 1.

`PackageManager.MatchDefaultOnly` to `PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY`

##### 2.

`PackageManager.ResolveInfoFlags` to `PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER`

Comment: The question is for Xamarin, not Android SDK

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `PackageManager.ResolveInfoFlags.of(PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)` :

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
         resolveInfo = context.getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intentToResolve, PackageManager.ResolveInfoFlags.of(PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY));
      } else {
         resolveInfo = context.getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intentToResolve, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
      }
```